# How to init view with nib file? How to manage view controllers in a project?

Tags: xcode, view, interface, builder

I've created new Single View project in Xcode. In ViewController.xib I've added new custom view inside another view. (grey rectangle)
[image]

Then I've created new files: "CoordinateSystemViewController".
[image]

Now, I want to init my custom view with CoordinateSystemViewController.xib.
I've tried (ViewController.m file):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CoordinateSystemViewController *coordinateSystemViewController = [[CoordinateSystemViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CoordinateSystemViewController" bundle:nil];
    coordinateSystemView = coordinateSystemViewController.view;


}
```

but it seems to be the wrong way because it doesn't work :P

Should I always create ViewController for each file?
Should every view be loaded from separate .xib file?
Is it a good habit to create one View Controller class with few views' IBOutlets which manages them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inorder to use another UIView inside Controller , We do not need to use another controller for it. Instead manage UIView inside same Controller.

Refer to [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html) for more Information.